# How to frame insert statements from select statement data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've selected some data from a table it gives some rows in as result. Now, I want to generate insert statements from result data in SQL Server.

Please suggest me any solutions.

Comment: Why cant you use the select statement directly to insert into another table

Comment: no,i do't want create a table but i need sql quires from the result like insert into values('','','') like this manner.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination table is a new table,
you may use `SQL SELECT INTO Statement`.

We can copy all columns into the new table:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

Or we can copy only the columns we want into the new table:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

The new table will be created with the column-names and types as defined in the SELECT statement. You can apply new names using the AS clause.

Comment: no,i do't want create a table but i need sql quires from the result  like insert into values('','','') like this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
SELECT 'insert into tabledestination (col1destination,col2destination)
 values (' + col1source + ',' + col2source + ')' 
FROM   tablesource;
```

Comment: no,i do't want create a table but i need sql quires from the result like insert into values('','','') like this manner.

Comment: This gives you the same output in form of rows. Once you replace the column and table name appropriately , Executing this query will give you as
 "insert into tabledestination (FirstName,LastName)  values (' Learning ','New ')' " 
"insert into tabledestination (FirstName,LastName)  values ('Abc ','Def ')' " 
assuming that tablesource has two rows 
FirstName| LastName
learning    | New
Abc         | Def

Comment: @MeenaKrishnaKurra This query does creates table it gives you rows with your desired data(insert statement) whereas Other answers give you way to create table.

Comment: hey i dont want insert the data to any tables but i need the query framing ,by taking query reference i will update some data and inserts to other table example @ learingNew

Comment: @MeenaKrishnaKurra Try to execute the query once, Then you will get the idea what I am saying, This query **does not insert any data in any table**.